# pywinauto/others - getting opened tabs url from Edge

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have question about possibility to get url of all opened tabs in Edge browser.

I have started with pywinauto and I have possibility to get all tab names from Chrome or from Edge:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
desktop = Desktop(backend="uia")
window = desktop.windows(title_re="edge", control_type="Window")[0] # change title_re to "chrome" to get values for chrome browser
wrapper_list = window.descendants(control_type="TabItem")

tab_names = [tab.window_text() for tab in wrapper_list]
```

And yes, I'm getting all opened Edge tabs.

I have also checked the code below:

```
import pywinauto    
app = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia')
app.connect(title_re=".*Microsoft​ Edge.*", found_index=0)
dlg = app.top_window()
wrapper = dlg.child_window(title="App bar", control_type="ToolBar")
url = wrapper.descendants(control_type='Edit')[0]
print(url.get_value())
```

With no success - the "url = wrapper.descendants(control_type='Edit')[0]" returns error:
"ElementNotFound"

So... how to use it to get url of all the opened tabs? Or just one by using it's title?
It's not necessary to use pywinauto of course.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is more easier way to do that, and it do more, for example,get title of each tab:

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.edge.extension.is_installed():
    cc.edge.extension.install_or_update()

for browser in cc.edge.browsers:
    for tab in browser.tabs:
        print(tab.url)
```